# Runnnig Pytest while building docker compose up

Tags: docker, docker-compose, pytest

My projects structure looks as following.

```
app/
    docker-compose.yml
    test_some_pytest.py # this have some pytest code.
    tests.Dockerfile
```

my `tests.Dockerfile` looks as following.

```
from python:3.4-alpine
RUN python --version
RUN pip --version
COPY . /APP
WORKDIR /APP
RUN pip install pytest
RUN ["pytest"]
```

and `docker-compose.yml` as following.

```
services
  tests:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: tests.Dockerfile
```

When I run `docker-compose up --build tests`. the pytest also run but probably at some other place. it shows the following output.

```
.
.
.
Removing intermediate container 96f9a8ba43d2
 ---> 82c89715d4c0
Step 7/7 : RUN ["pytest"]
 ---> Running in c30ee497e5f5
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.4.10, pytest-4.6.11, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /python-test-calculator
collected 0 items

========================= no tests ran in 0.00 seconds =========================
The command 'pytest' returned a non-zero code: 5
ERROR: Service 'tests' failed to build : Build failed
```

Comment: Do you intend `pytest` to run at *build* time (when creating the image) or at *run* time (when starting the container)?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the behavior you've described. Using your Dockerfile, and placing a single test in `test_some_pytest.py`, the tests run successfully when `pytest` executes during the build process.

Comment: @larsks, at build time. would you mind put your code structure and file code as answer or probably over a pastebin link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I use your `tests.Dockerfile` exactly as written, the following `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: "3"

services:
  tests:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: tests.Dockerfile
```

And the following `test_some_pytest.py`:

```
def test_something():
    assert True
```

It successfully runs `pytest` when I run `docker-compose build`:

```
$ docker-compose build
Building tests

[...]

Step 7/7 : RUN ["pytest"]
 ---> Running in 8d8a1f44913f
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.4.10, pytest-4.6.11, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /APP
collected 1 item

test_some_pytest.py .                                                    [100%]

=========================== 1 passed in 0.01 seconds ===========================
Removing intermediate container 8d8a1f44913f
 ---> 055afd5b1f8d
Successfully built 055afd5b1f8d
Successfully tagged docker_tests:latest
```

You can see from the above output that `pytest` discovered and successfully ran 1 test.

Comment: Thanks @larsks, somehow I seems to missed have something. now when I tried again. it works. anychance you have idea why I can't make an get request to my localhost from pytest it says ```Connection Error/ Connection Refused```?

Comment: `localhost` inside a docker container means "this container". If you want to access a service running on your host, you need to use the ip address of one of your host's non-`localhost` interfaces.